# heroku app not found when adding a domain

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I would like to add a domain `whatever.com` to a heroku app that I collaborate on named `whatever`. When I type `$ heroku domains` it gives `! App not found`.

How can I set the app I want to use, and then have it use `$ heroku domains:add whatever.com`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're in a directory that is linked to a herkou app if you want to issue commands without specifying an app name.  Alternatively, you can add the --app= parameter to your command to explicitly specify the app you want the heroku command to run on.

```
$ heroku domains:add whatever.com --app=whatever
```